# Problem while installing Pycairo on my computer

Tags: python, pycairo

I am currently trying to install PyCairo on my computer, I am using Python 3.7.5 on a 64bits system.

So I take the file from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycairo and then I select the "pycairo‑1.18.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl" file.

After that, I try to install it and here is what I have:

```html
Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.18362.476]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\hp\Documents\Manim>python -m pip install pycairo-1.18.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: pycairo-1.18.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I should mention that I am a total beginner, I did my research but I didn't found anything similar to my problem, thanks for your help.

Comment: You might have a 32-bit version of Python installed, which would need `*-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl` wheels. Also `python` might refer to another Python installation. Try specifying the full path to `python.exe`.